# How do I read a single line from file and transform it to number array? (octave)

Tags: matlab, line, octave, scanf

I have a text file with this format:

```
number_of_lines
x1_values y1_values
x2_values y2_values
.
.
.
xn_values yn_values
```

After I scanned number_of_lines, how can I read the rest line by line and separate them into xk, respectively yk?

(If there are 8 values on a line, the first 4 will be x's and the other 4 will be y's. There are only numbers.)

Comment: Have you looked at fscanf?

Comment: are there more lines than `number_of_lines+1` in that file?

Answer (score 0):

I created a file "yourdata":

```
5
10 20
20 30
30 25
40 55
50 60
```

then use for example fscanf, or textread with headerlines or fscanf and textscan.

```
fid = fopen ("yourdata", "r");
lines = fscanf (fid, "%d", 1)
[d] = fscanf (fid, "%f", [lines, 2]);
fclose (fid);

x = d(:, 1)
y = d(:, 2)
```

gives

```
lines =  5
x =

   10
   20
   20
   30
   30

y =

   25
   40
   55
   50
   60
```